# Sql error in c# - MVC 3

Tags: c#, sql

I keep getting an error saying:

> Incorrect syntax near c"(sql error

But I can't see a reason why. I've ran this in Studio Management and it runs without any problems.
Here is my method:

```
public string GetSecurityDetails(int contactId)
{
    ContactId = contactId;

    using (DataAccess da = new DataAccess())
    {
        da.Execute("SELECT c.ContactId,c.SecurityQuestionAnswer,q.Name" +
                   "FROM profile.SecurityQuestion q" +
                   "INNER JOIN profile.Contact c ON q.SecurityQuestionID = c.SecurityQuestionFK" +
                   "WHERE c.ContactID = @Contact",new SqlParameter("@Contact",contactId));

        while(da.Read())
        {
            SecurityAnswer = da.GetValue<string>("securityQuestionAnswer");
            SecurityQuestion = da.GetValue<string>("Name");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 3 in Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: At least you ar missing a space after `profile.SecurityQuestion q` and also after `q.SecurityQuestionID = c.SecurityQuestionFK`

Comment: There are a few spaces missing e.g. qINNER JOIN is not valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missing spaces in your query:

```
da.Execute(
           "SELECT c.ContactId,c.SecurityQuestionAnswer,q.Name FROM profile.SecurityQuestion q " +
           "INNER JOIN profile.Contact c ON q.SecurityQuestionID = c.SecurityQuestionFK " +
           "WHERE c.ContactID = @Contact",new SqlParameter("@Contact",contactId)
           );
```

But i will use `@` before string so it can be multiline:

```
da.Execute(
           @"SELECT c.ContactId,c.SecurityQuestionAnswer,q.Name FROM profile.SecurityQuestion q
           INNER JOIN profile.Contact c ON q.SecurityQuestionID = c.SecurityQuestionFK
           WHERE c.ContactID = @Contact",new SqlParameter("@Contact",contactId)
           );
```

Comment: Thank you Uriil. I think I will use @ next time

Answer (score 0):

Look like you are missing a space in profile.SecurityQuestion **q "** +
and another one in q.SecurityQuestionID = **c.SecurityQuestionFK "** +